# Why is there no mode complete for file-sink?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

Looking at the spark [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#output-sinks) about different available output sinks for structured streaming, I wonder, why there is no support for a writing complete (i.e. aggregated streaming results) to files?
What is a current workaround?

(as I couldn't find any table support in Stackoverflow, even not with standard html table tags, I hope that the link stays active a bit longer)

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

HDFS write only allows to append content at the end of file, which cannot enable update mode as well as complete mode (which requires overwrite value on same key). So there's no workaround on it.